# Woes in trapping valueForKeyPath: without a valid path

Tags: nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary, key-value-observing, keypaths

I have a nested `NSMutableDictionary` and am successfully pulling out a value at some 'depth' nested in other dictionaries, like:

`NSNumber *num = [myDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"league.team.away.score"];`

All is good.  And I can confirm that all dictionaries at all levels are mutable.

**But... what if that key path does not exist?**

As expected, I get an `NSUndefinedKeyException`.  I tried a fix with a try/catch tactic, to no avail.

[Apple's](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1413457-valueforundefinedkey?language=objc) solution to this concerns overriding `valueForUndefinedKey`:

*"Subclasses can override this method to return an alternate value for undefined keys. The default implementation raises an NSUndefinedKeyException."*

Great... so I create a subclass `NSMutableDictionaryMod`, then I get a complaint...
*`[NSMutableDictionary initWithCapacity:]` method only defined for abstract class.  Define -[NSMutableDictionaryMod initWithCapacity:]!*

I go define said initializer (and can confirm it gets there in Xcode), but *boom* it crashes on the `self = [super initWithCapacity:numItems];` line.

Then I noticed this [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutabledictionary?language=objc) gem on `NSMutableDictionary`:

*There should typically be little need to subclass NSMutableDictionary. If you do need to customize behavior, it is often better to consider composition rather than subclassing.*

**Any suggestions would be appreciated.**

Comment: `-[NSDictinary valueForKeyPath:]` resturns `nil` if the key path does not exist. Does a key start with "@"? Does `[myDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"league.team"]` resturn a `NSString`? Please post the error.

Comment: valueForKeyPath throws an `NSUndefinedKeyException`, as per the docs.  I wish it returned nil.  Key does not start with a "@".  For my example, "score" is a key to an `NSNumber` in a parent away dictionary; "away" is a key in a parent team dictionary; "team"is a key in a parent league dictionary; "league" is a key in `myDictionary`.  In other words, `[myDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"league.team"]` is a dictionary.

Comment: `valueForUndefinedKey` throws a `NSUndefinedKeyException`, `valueForKeyPath` doesn't. Don't you see an error like `[<__NSCFConstantString 0x100003120> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key someKey`? Did you set an exception breakpoint?